# What is the correct way to override Application.getResourceBundle() in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I'd like to use a specific `ResourceBundle.Control` for **ALL** resource bundles used by JSF.

Therefore, I created an `ApplicationWrapper` (+ `ApplicationFactory`) which overrides the `getResourceBundle()` method.

The strange behaviour I am noticing is that `getResourceBundle()` is called each time an expression containing named objects is evaluated.

For example, if my template contains some expression like `"#{someBean.active and securityBean.secure}"` then `getResourceBundle()` will be called once with "someBean" as basename and once with "securityBean".

This does not seem very efficient and I may be missing something (and I really don't know why would JSF do that for each named object).

I am using mojarra bundled with wildfly 14.

Answer (score 0):

`getResourceBundle()` is not meant to load any resource bundle, it is the equivalent of `<application><resource-bundle>...` and it takes a logical name, not the basename of the bundle. So this question has no sense.

Comment: I might have read the question wrong, but I nowhere see the OP stating he/she is loading the resourcebundle in the method

Comment: I thought it was implied by the fact that I wanted to use a ResourceBundle.Control. Is there any other way to use one in JSF without calling getBundle() yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I missed you are the OP, sorry. Your answer is correct if you actualy loaded things in there each time...